# Outlook - Interop asking if I want to approve a certificate

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I'm using interop to get me a list of all local outlook contacts (code below). It all works fine except for one case: When I don't have outlook open during the time Iam using that code I get a messagebox which disappears after about 2 seconds again. The messagebox asks me (translated thus the english version is probably slightly different): "Configuring mailboxxyz-accept Server configuration for this website?"

After looking at the message and looking how the local things are configured I saw that my company is using a certificate in outlook and as it is looking it is so that:

- If outlook is running then my interop functions are using the certificate and thus the messagebox does not pop up
- If outlook is not running then my interop functions are not automatically using the certificate and thus the popup comes and asks if I want to accept it.

What adds a layer of strangeness there is that the usage of the functions succeeds and the messagebox pops up a few seconds AFTER the functions have finished and then disappears after 2 seconds.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookHandler = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookItemsCollection;
MAPIFolder folderContacts = (MAPIFolder)outlookHandler.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
outlookItemsCollection = folderContacts.Items;

foreach (var outlookItem in outlookItemsCollection)
{
    .....
}
```

Also another way to get this phenomenon: When outlook is not running I can try to start it:

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookHandler = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        var mm = outlookHandler.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        mm.Logon(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, true); 
        // Same for the second true being false instead.
```

When I do this outlook asks for the certificate after asking for the default profile.

My question here is now: Is there any way to prevent this popup from happening (or to tell the interop methods to use the certificate without asking)?

Comment: Added a bit more info after additional tests

Comment: Is it that each outlook client has a certificate, or that the exchange server is using a certificate which outlook clients have to accept?

Comment: The exchange server is using a certificate as far as I'm aware

Comment: It sounds to me like you might be getting an SSL error and that's causing your interop to fall over. I could be wrong though. Is your program throwing any exceptions at all?

Comment: no no exceptions thrown at all not even a warning

Comment: You may wish to set the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Application.Visible property to true to see what the prompts are telling you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to preface this with the fact that this isn't an elegant solution, it should however work.

```
// check to see if outlook is running
System.Diagnostics.Process[] prcs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook");
// if the found prcs length is 0, outlook isn't running
if(prcs.Length == 0)
{
    // start outlook
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path to outlook");
    // wait for outlook to load
    // call your interop code
}
else
    // outlook was found as an open process
    // call your interop code
```

This works around your issue rather than resolving the underlying issue. Without an exception or anything else it's difficult to actually get to the bottom of.